# Update to 1.9.2.4 breaks custom Sales Order Grid mass Action

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, export, massaction, ce-1.9.2.4

I have added a new mass action on the sales order grid. It worked flawlessly on all 1.9.x releases up to 1.9.2.4 upgrade from 1.9.2.2 so I suspect this is now broken by the new security features that require me to white list Variables and Blocks.

The following code adds and enables the mass action (order export to SCV).

**/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php**
..

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('export_selected', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('(new) Export to CSV'),
              'url'  =>$this->getUrl('*/*/massExport', array('_current'=>true)),
        ));
```

..

**/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php**
..

```
public function massExportAction()
     {
         //$productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
         $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_ids');
         if (!is_array($orderIds)) {
             $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select orders(s).'));
             $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
         }
         else {
             //write headers to the csv file
             $content = '"order_number","customer_name","customer_email"';
             try {
                 foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
                     $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->load($orderId);
                     $content .= "\"{$order->getIncrementId()}\",\"{$order->getCustomerName()}\",\"{$order->getCustomerEmail()}\"\r\n";
                 }
             } catch (Exception $e) {
                 $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
                 $this->_redirect('*/*/');
             }
             $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('orders-export-'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'.csv', $content, 'text/csv');
         }

     }
```

..

As of 1.9.2.4 calling the function from the Sales Order Grid in the admin interface results in no file being created and 404 that points to frontend..

Any recommendations on what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your `var/log/exceptions.log` and `var/log/system.log` for any helpful error message from Magento? Furthermore did you make sure that the block you get via `getMassactionBlock()` is whitelisted?

From 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.2.4 there was no major security fix that would cause such an impact as far as I remember.

Another question is if the 404 occurs when calling the massAction or the redirects?

Comment: I would whitelist it, but what is the block name/identifier for this specific block to white list?

Comment: If it is a problem with not whitelisted blocks you would be able to see that in the logs - even the name/identifier to whitelist. Are you sure the 404 happens when calling the massExportAction and not the redirect?

Comment: This error reporting is enabled in logs, and I have white listed other blocks in this way. It does not create a whitelist entry in the logs for this action, so it seems not to be a whitelist issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

Magento **core controllers classes** cannot be override from local `codePool` with Mage  `NamespSace(/app/code/local/Mage/)`.

You need to override at proper way.

Please follow the below link

[Override a controller in Adminhtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10454/override-a-controller-in-adminhtml)

[How can I extend/override admin controller for login?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32157/how-can-i-extend-override-admin-controller-for-login)

[Magento override Adminhtml Customer Controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94471/magento-override-adminhtml-customer-controller)